# Add key, values dynamically to a dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

Given a path(keys) in list, need to add value to given dictionary

```
data = {'personal_information': {'name' : {'first_name': 'Ashutosh'}}}
path_to_add = ['personal_information', 'address': 'state']
value = 'Delhi'

expected_output = {'personal_information': {'name' : {'first_name': 'Ashutosh'}}, 'address': {'state': 'Delhi'}}
```

Comment: The value of `path_to_add` doesn't seem to correspond to `expected_output`. Shouldn't the result be `{'personal_information': {'name' : {'first_name': 'Ashutosh'}, 'address': {'state': 'Delhi'}}}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using recursion:

```py
data = {'personal_information': {'name' : {'first_name': 'Ashutosh'}}}
path_to_add = ['personal_information', 'address', 'state']
value = 'Delhi'

def addValue(dictionary, path, value):
    if len(path) > 1:
        if path[0] not in dictionary.keys():
            dictionary[path[0]] = {}
        addValue(dictionary[path[0]], path[1:], value)
    else:
        dictionary[path[0]] = value

print(data)
addValue(data, path_to_add, value)
print(data)
```

Outputs:

```py
{'personal_information': {'name': {'first_name': 'Ashutosh'}}}
{'personal_information': {'name': {'first_name': 'Ashutosh'}, 'address': {'state': 'Delhi'}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop over the path sliced to the last element and work through the object using `setdefault()` to create new objects as needed. After the loop you'll have a reference to the last object that you can use to set the value:

```
data = {'personal_information': {'name' : {'first_name': 'Ashutosh'}}}
path_to_add = ['personal_information', 'address', 'state']
value = 'Delhi'

def add_to_dict(data, path, value):
    found = data
    for key in path[0:-1]:
        found = found.setdefault(key, {})
    found[path[-1]] = value

add_to_dict(data, path_to_add, value)
print(data)
```

**Result:**

```
{'personal_information': {'name': {'first_name': 'Ashutosh'}, 'address': {'state': 'Delhi'}}}
```